# Printer over the network

Tags: windows-xp, networking, printer, windows-server-2003

The printer is able to accomodate 10 users printing at the same time, but there are almost 30 users connecting to the printer.

I just want to ask, is there a way or is this possible if the driver of the printer is installed in the server and users are connecting through server, is there a chance to exceed the maximum limit of users printing (10 at the same time)?

Would it be possible that all users can print to the printer at the same time?

Server OS in Windows Server 2k3.
client OS is XP.

Comment: If there are 30 users trying to print at the same time as it seems in your case, the simplest solution would be to buy two more printers. Multiple users can't print simultaneously per se - only que up. If your printer ques up 30 users at once it will still only print one document at a time. You also haven't mentioned what priter you are using.

Comment: As Sandokan mentioned, you should edit your question to add information about the printer manufacturer and model number. Also, describe how you are connecting to the printer now (USB, Ethernet ... ?), and give some more details about why you think *`the printer is able to accomodate 10 users printing at the same time.`*

Answer (score 0):

"The printer is able to accomodate 10 users"  What does this mean?  How does the printer know if 10 people are printing to it or not?  If you have a Windows Server with the printer installed any number of users should be able to print to it.  Unless you have a windows license that does not permit more than 10 concurrent users to attach to the server at the same time.

Your biggest issue is the monthly duty cycle of the printer.  If the specs say the printer can only handle a 1,000 pages a month then having 30 users attach will likely exceed this number.  This shorten the printers life span.